# como deletar o arquivo .bat que estou usando

Tags: bat

Estou tentando fazer um joguinho com .bat, ele funciona assim: eu faço uma pergunta, se o jogador acertar ele continua o jogo, mas se ele errar apaga o arquivo do jogo. Porém eu não sei programar muito bem.

já vi alguns fóruns, mas nenhum dos que eu vi me ajudaram

Answer (score 0):

Você pode apagar arquivos utilizando o comando

```
del nome_do_arquivo
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o comando a baixo na sua condição, apagara o próprio .bat que esta sendo executado:

```
del %0
```

Cuidado, salve o conteúdo antes, senão ira acabar perdendo.